# SQL query to group results based on field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table has 4 fields columns; id, cinema_id, movie_id, showing_at.

```
id - Integer(primary key)
cinema_id - Integer(foreign key)
movie_id - Integer(foreign key)
showing_at - Datetime
```

Am trying to come up with a query that retrieves the result from table based on the movie_id column and a date, and groups the results using the cinema_id;
My current query looks like this using laravel

```
$models = DB::table('showtimes')->where('movie_id', $movie_id)
                                        ->whereBetween('showing_at', [$date." 00:00", $date." 23:00"])
                                        ->groupBy('cinema_id')
                                        ->get();
```

The dumped query result looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 161
            [cinema_id] => 1
            [movie_id] => 15
            [showing_at] => 2016-03-20 12:20:00
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 145
            [cinema_id] => 3
            [movie_id] => 15
            [showing_at] => 2016-03-20 10:00:00
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 
        )

)
```

How do i query the db to group all the showtimes under cinema_id

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How do i query the db to group all the showtimes under cinema_id

Comment: I was looking for sometime like cinema_id => array of showtimes

Comment: I think this should be done in the application end rather than the database query. In my case I'd just query for the results and then group them based on key filed for an hierarchical array.